# Combined arithmetic and geometric series question

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

Here is a combined arithmetic and geometric series question -

> *The first, the tenth and the twentieth terms of an increasing
> arithmetic sequence are also consecutive terms in an increasing geometric
> sequence. Find the common ratio of the geometric sequence.*
>
> *[10 marks]*

Here's what I have done so far,

$\Rightarrow\ U_1 = a =  V_1$

$\Rightarrow\ U_{10} = a + 9d = V_2$

$\Rightarrow\ U_{20} = a + 19d = V_3$

Well, that's all I can derive from the question. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: $U_{10}^2=U_{20}.U_{10}$ Try using this. You will get know something about a and d. then using ${U_{10} \over U_1}=r$ you can get the common ratio.

Comment: @JayantJha - Yes, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the common ratio $R$. Hence

$R= \frac{V_2}{V_1}$ and $R= \frac{V_3}{V_2}$.

This gives

$(a+9d)^2=a^2+19ad$, hence $a=81d.$

Therefore $R=1+9 \frac{d}{a}=\frac{10}{9}.$

Comment: OMG! Thanks a bunch for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your attempt, I have:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_1=b_1
\\ a_1+9d=b_1\cdot q
\\ a_1+19d=b_1\cdot q^2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Solving, I obtain:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_1=b_1
\\ b_1(q-1)=9d
\\ b_1(q-1)(q+1)=19d
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Substituting, I obtain:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_1=b_1
\\ a_1+9d=b_1\cdot q
\\ 9d(q+1)=19d
\end{matrix}\right.$$

From here I have $q=\frac{10}{9}$.

Comment: Thanks, Matteo for your help. This was really helpful.